# How to update div text content accordingly

Tags: jquery

When the plus icon is clicked , how can i updated the quantity present in another div ??

[image]

The div that is responsible for quantity is

```
HTML.append('<div  id_attr2="'+id_attr+'" style="display:inline-block" >'+quantity+'</div>');
```

On click of the plus  button , i tried to increment a variable named quantity which is initaillay hardcoded to 1 but it showing same for all the items

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZKRz/1/

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".buttontest", function() {
    var $id = $(this).prevAll("input").first().attr("id");
    if($(this).hasClass("inc")){
        $(".cart").find("div").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("id_attr")==$id){
              $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text(),10)+amountdd);
            }
        });
    }else if($(this).hasClass("dec")){
        $(".cart").find("div").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("id_attr")==$id){

            $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text(),10)-amountdd);
            }
        });
    }
    });
```

Could anybody please tell me How to update quantity div text content accordingly

Comment: check my ans for a script to start with

Comment: you just copied and pasted it you have to modify it change the classes according to your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it! You just need to use the [$.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function to get the next sibling then update its quantity

```
$(this).text(parseInt($(this).text(),10)+amountdd);
var $quantElm = $(this).next();
var quant = parseInt($quantElm.text());
$quantElm.text(quant + 1);
```

similarly for decremented.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZKRz/4/)

Answer (score 0):

use this script for a start

html

```
<div class="num">0</div>//div whose number is to be imcremented
<div class="add1">add+</div>//div to cause the imcrement
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".add1").click(dunction(){

       var select_counter  = $(".num");//the div whose number to increment
       var get_num = parseInt(select_counter.text());//get the number
       select_counter.html(get_num + 1);//increment it

  }
}
```

Comment: Please see the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4ZKRz/3/  but its showing the same value for quantity for all the items .